# Losing child node in BST left rotation Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am working on an assignment that requires us to implement rotation in a BST. However, halfway through my implementation I lose the child value in my method and I cannot seem to implement it back into the tree. Are my steps wrong?

For example for the tree (in level order) [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7] the '3' goes missing in my Java method when the parent (valueParent) is 2 and the child (valueChild) is 3. I expect the array [4, 3, 6, 2, 5, 7, 1] but I get[ 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 7 ]
My steps:

1. Set valueParent's right child to be valueChild's left child
2. Set the valueChild's left-child's parent to be valueParent
3. Set valueChild's left child to be valueParent
4. Set valueParent's parent to be valueChild

```
private void rotate(Node<T> valueChild, Node<T> valueParent) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        //left rotation
        if (valueChild == null)throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if (valueChild.isRightChild() == true){
        //the line below is where '3' is removed forever
        valueParent.rightChild = valueChild.leftChild;
        if (valueChild.leftChild != null) valueChild.leftChild.parent = valueParent;
        valueParent.leftChild.parent = valueParent;
        valueChild.leftChild = valueParent;
        valueChild.parent = valueParent.parent;
        valueParent.parent = valueChild;
}
```

Any help or explanation would be appreciated, I cannot figure out why the child node continues to get dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. I was not accounting for certain edgecases when rotating.

```
if (valueChild.isRightChild() == true) {
            valueParent.rightChild = valueChild.leftChild;
            if (valueChild.leftChild != null)
                valueChild.leftChild.parent = valueParent;
            valueChild.parent = valueParent.parent;
            if (valueParent.parent == null)
                this.root = valueChild;
            else if (valueParent == valueParent.parent.leftChild)
                valueParent.parent.leftChild = valueChild;
            else{ valueParent.parent.rightChild = valueChild;}
            valueChild.leftChild = valueParent;
            valueParent.parent = valueChild;
            //perform left rotation
        }
```

This implementation correctly rotates the tree mentioned above.